# Liveengage iframe tag with bootstrap the button gets cut off

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to integrate a live engage button tag into a website. This is the code:

```
<div id="LP_DIV_xxxxxxxxxxxxx">
```

This uses the live engage javascript to create an iframe which contains the content and makes the link. At first I couldn't get the image to line up with the rest of the div. So I found the "embed-responsive" class in bootstrap and I applied that but now the image gets "cut off" although it is now properly aligned. Please see the image I have provided. Does anyone know how I can make this not blow out the div and show the entire image?

[image]

Comment: Maybe its  the height of your image..

Comment: Show a proper [mcve], please.

Comment: Sorry it turns out that Live engage has a position offset in their app that you have to set to 0,0 unless you want it to be crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it turns out that Live engage has a position offset in their app that you have to set to 0,0 unless you want it to be crazy.